# Как подгрузить локальный файл через ajax без интернета и сервера?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть верстка проекта - обычный html+jquery.
Допустим есть код:

```
$.ajax({url:"text1.text"}).success(function(data){ alert(data); });
```

Выдает ошибку:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file.

Но надо чтобы файл подгрузился именно локально.
Поставить локальный сервер или подтягивать из интернета не вариант.

Надо чтобы верстку можно было взять с собой на флешке и продемонстрировать на компьютере где нет интернета, локального сервера, прав администратора.

Допустим, я пишу приложения на angular2 + bootstrap 4, использую предпроцессоры, gulp'ы всякие, а backend тяну только через api. Ок. Все понимаю, но и велосипеды пишу.
Но тут просто html+jquery. Надо чтобы верстку демонстрировал совершенно другой человек (любой) и только со флешки.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`XMLHttpRequest` работает только с `http`, `data`, `https`.
Хром ещё позволяет `chrome`, `chrome-extension`, `chrome-extension-resource`, что понятно, но не помогает, ибо специфично.

---

Вам поможет миниатюрный сервер типа портативного `XAMPP`, запускаемого Bash-скриптиком. Или батником, если винда.

---

Если и это невозможно, то слейте всё в один файл, декорируйте API jQuery на перехват локальных путей и возврат их содержимого как бы загруженного.

Answer (score 2):

Насколько мне известно, этого нельзя сделать. AJAX подразумевает общение через http-протокол. Могу вам посоветовать визуально имитировать работу AJAX-запроса — показывать скрытый на странице блок при нужном событии.

Answer (score 2):

Запустить локальный сервер проще, чем вы думаете. Очень многие веб-сервера могут быть запущены прямо с флешки в один клик. Надо просто их прямо на эту самую флешку установить.

Для работы без прав администратора надо всего-навсего слушать адрес 127.0.0.1 (он же localhost) - этот адрес обычно не закрыт брандмауэром. И любой порт больше 1024 (порт 80 может быть занят Скайпом или стандартным IIS).

Как минимум, на флешку можно поставить Apache Server, nginx и IIS Express. Также простейший локальный сервер можно написать на NodeJs

На ту же самую флешку можно записать любой браузер, чтобы не гадать что будет на "том компьютере".

Если вам нужны изкоробочные решения - посмотрите открытый проект [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/).